# Strange Increase of ANR on Google Play Console Since May 19

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-anr-dialog

[Game 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq1uD.png)

[Game 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w53HH.png)

[Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMIm3.png)

Hi Guys, I've encountered strange increase of ANRs in several apps. I wonder if your apps have the same problem and how you fix it. Here are some details:

1. The increase started from about May 19, 2021, in all versions.
2. The ANR is not a new one, but its frequency has suddenly increased recently.
3. "Stack trace not available" on Google Play Console.

Thanks for your read and look forward to your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've tagged myself to follow this thread, same behaviour seen with our [Game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FpMp.png)
Android 12 beta was launched on 18 of May, on that day the ANR has started triggering on other Android versions. This is currently our only lead.

These spikes appeared in between of our updates, so we assume the cause is external.

Comment: Hi, our programmer assumes that was due to the old version of Admob SDK. developers.google.com/admob/android/migration. It seems that SDK v20 has big changes in API. Are your game still using SDK v19.5?

Comment: We indeed have an older version, v20 has really big changes and it would fit the bigger picture.
Good catch, we'll have to update our SDKs as well for our next patch.
 
Hopefully we'll see a drop in cases, if you get your update out sooner, would appreciate if you could share your findings/data, to make sure AdMob was the root cause :)

Comment: Did either of you ever discover whether Admob was the root cause? Or did your ANR rates stay high?

Answer (score 0):

If it's between upgrades, it can be due to increase in the dex load time.
In that case baseline profiles should help.
refer this for more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJm5On5Gp4c

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33303195)